# Maven - how to build a jar for every java package

Tags: java, maven, build

Is it possible to build a jar for every java package in a project?

e.g. my packages are `com.mypackage.foo, com.mypackage.bar` both packages are in one project.
Can i now start a maven build to get a foo.jar and a bar.jar?

Thanks 4 the help.

**EDIT:** Okay, I think you need some more informations why I am asking that.
I have a project which is divided in two parts (a library and a daemon) and both parts must be runnable independent from each other, so I want to use a own jar for each part.
I was thinking about a "parent project" that includes the two parts as modules like some of you suggested (is that a nicer way?).
The next point is that I have only one git repo in that I want to commit the whole project. Is it possiple to place the modules projects content in the parent project like `src/lib/java` or how I have to do that?

Comment: Why do you need such a weird thing? May be you need several modules which would result in several jar's.

Comment: thanks for the many answers and suggestions, all vote up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maven the conventions is to build a jar for a module which means in other words
to build a jar from the contents of `src/main/java`. If you need to build a jar from every packages that sounds a little bit weird to me. 
You can do things like this but this is **not recommended** cause it will result in trouble later. This is a kind of fight you start with Maven which you will loose in the end.

You need to configure the [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>...</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <include>com/mypackage/foo/**</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a project for every package to adhere to Maven conventions.
A quick question, why do you need to do that?

Comment: You're definitely on the good track, a Maven multi-module project can be placed on a single git repository. This SO question should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841440/eclipse-maven-git-multi-module-projects-unhappiness

Comment: so this is the right structure? http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/923/screenwfi.png

Answer (score 2):

The [maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) can be configured to include and exclude classes. So it would be easy to just package all classes from one package:

```
     <includes>
        <include>com/example/foo/*</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>com/example/foo/subfoo1/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/example/foo/subfoo2/**</exclude>
        <!-- to exclude all packages that start with com.example.foo -->
      </excludes>
```

But you'd have to write a pom file for each and every single package... You could create on additional multi-module pom, that runs all those modules and you could even auto-generate the pom files with a small java programm, although it's quite challenging to auto-detect all packages that would go into the jars in advance.

---

It may be easier to use the [maven AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and define a `<target>` that calls the [jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) for each package.

---

The multi-module structure could be like this:

```
./
 pom.xml
 project/
        src/...
        target/...
        pom1.xml
        pom2.xml
        pom3.xml
```

it was my understanding, that all java packages reside in the same project. If the packages are in different projects, then you wouldn't have any trouble packaging them in different jars - that would be the default behavior.

Comment: so this could be the structure for a multi-module solution? http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/923/screenwfi.png